# how to build up a buffer overflow payload

Tags: c, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, stack-memory

I'm following this writeup on a buffer overflow of an array on the stack, doing a ROP attack to call a function that wouldn't normally be called.

There are three functions. vuln,flag and main.

main just calls vuln and vuln has a stackoverflow with 180 bytes.

```
int main()
{
  vuln();
}

void vuln()
{
  char buf[180];
  gets(buf);
}
```

flag is not called and has two parameters:

```
void flag(int param1, int param2) { }
```

It exists on address 0x080491e2.

flasg can be called by overflowing the buffer of 180 with 8 extra bytes and then add the address which EIP gets.

```
python -c "print('A'*188 + '\xe2\x91\x04\x08')"
```

So far so good, flag is called but without parameters.
To call flag with parameters we have to add 'A'*4 after flag's address and the two values of the integers with a '\r' between them.

```
python -c "print('A'*188 + '\xe2\x91\x04\x08'+'A'*4+'\xef\xbe\xad\xde\r\xd0\xde\xc0')"
```

I dont understand why the 'A'*4 is needed, what stack parts is overwritten here?
And also the '\r' between the arguments, if it's not there it's not working.
What function does the '\r' have?

Comment: Isn't what you're trying just using a buffer overflow (or more specifically a "stack buffer overflow") to manipulate the stack and not a stack overflow?

Comment: It depends how the compiler chooses to lay out the stack frame of `vuln()`, whether there's any padding for alignment.  i.e. you need to look at the asm, not the C source.

Comment: @StefanRiedel: Yes, that's correct, this is a *buffer* overflow on the stack, not a *stack overflow* (where you try to use more stack space than the stack growth limit, so you segfault, e.g. with alloca or VLAs, or deep recursion and/or big local arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AAAA` are because on entry to `flag`, it expects the top of the stack to contain its return address, with arguments starting 4 bytes past that.  You don't care about `flag` being able to return, so you just need 4 bytes of garbage in place of the return address.

As for the `\r`, it isn't between the arguments (they should be adjacent in memory and there can't be any bytes between them); rather it is actually the first (least-significant) byte of the second argument.    The ASCII carriage return `\r` has numerical value `0x0d`, so your arguments are `0xdeadbeef, 0xc0ded00d`.  I don't know why they wrote the low byte as `\r` instead of `\x0d` which would have been more consistent.  Maybe it was automatically translated from binary to hex escapes by some program.